# Where is there a reliable place to get the other components for making Ammo?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've been playing Hardcore in New Vegas and I am always only finding ammo cases. I can't seem to find any traders who sell any of the other components needed to craft ammunition (though I haven't checked out out the New Vegas traders or the Gun Runners but I'm only up to the 188 Trading Post)

So I am wondering, where is there a reliable place to get the other components for making Ammo?

Answer (score 5):

The most reliable way is actually other ammunition.

You can generally breakdown ammo of the same general class of weapon to make another type.  Check the results in a workbench and breakdown ammo that you do not use.

The rarest component to make ammo *is* the casing (.357, 10mm, etc.), followed by primers along with powders (large rifle, pistol, ect.) and then of course, lead.

However, once you get access to later weapon dealers, like gun runners, McCarren, etc., you can readily buy all the parts.